# Navigation Drawer slightly overlaps Action Bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

I've made a Navigation Drawer for my app. I'm having trouble aligning the Navigation Drawer to be underneath the Action Bar. This is what I have in my XML:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include layout="@layout/app_bar_main" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main" app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I have tried both `android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"` and `android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"` but I still get the slight overlapping you can see in the photo below:

[image: Exhibit A]

This is what app_bar_main.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: please paste your app_bar_main layout also

Comment: hey how did you resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Change `android:fitsSystemWindows="false"` in NavigationView, DrawerLayout and CoordinatorLayout. This while remove the overlap. But you'll send up with a white Status Bar.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `fitSystemWindows` attribute to `false` for the NavigationView. However the [design guidelines](https://www.google.co.in/design/spec/patterns/navigation-drawer.html#navigation-drawer-specs) suggest that Navigation drawers should appear above the ActionBar so you might want to reconsider..

Answer (score 0):

You could try this out.

```
 <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- You could directly use your toolbar instead -->        
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" 
app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <!-- Put your content here -->

            <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView 
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start" 
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main" 
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```